# What does this <[T1, T2, T2]> syntax do in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I've stumbled upon this line of code in a TypeScript function. I assume that it is casting `someVar` into something, but I don't know what it is.

```ts
<[AdditionalInformation, IDataLookup[], IDataLookup[]]>someVar
```

I have not been able to find any answers in the TypeScript documentation. Does anyone know what this does?

Comment: It is a type cast/assertion, see [4.16 Type Assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#416-type-assertions).

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: It's definitely no JavaScript syntax :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax is to cast your variable.

In your case, an array with three value :

- One `AdditionalInformation` (Object `someVar[0]`)
- Two Arrays of `IDataLookup` (`someVar[1]` and `someVar[2]`)

An other example of Type Assertions in TypeScript :

```
<[string, number, null]>myVar = ["Hello World", 3, null];
```

You can check Type Assertions [in the TypeScript documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#416-type-assertions)

Answer (score 1):

It is a type cast/assertion, see [4.16 Type Assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#416-type-assertions).

In the above code you have cast `someVar` to an array with 3 elements where the 1st element is of type `AdditionalInformation` and the 2nd and 3rd elements are both of type `IDataLookup[]`.

Example code:

```
var tmp = <[AdditionalInformation, IDataLookup[], IDataLookup[]]>someVar;
tmp[0]./*methods and properties of type AdditionalInformation are accessible here*/
tmp[1]./*array of IDataLookup is accessible here*/
tmp[2]./*array of IDataLookup is accessible here*/
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a combination of cast and definition of array with individually typed indexes.

Cast 1:

```
var myVar:T = <T>someVar;
```

Cast 2 (types simplified):

```
var myVar:[number, boolean, string] = <[number, boolean, string]>someVar;
```

This will create a var with type of array, where index 0 can only contain a number, index 1 a bool, index 2 a string.